# Using Path Parameters on a post method in a micro services

Tags: java, angularjs-directive

Could someone kindly advice on whether its possible to use path params on a POST method.I have this POST method that does not seem to receive the path parameters

```
@Override
public Response addName(@PathParam("fname") String fName,
                           @PathParam("sname") String sName,
                           @PathParam("idno") String idNo) {
   System.out.println("Inside add User");


   return Response.status(200).entity("User Added").build();
 }
```

A post request to this method does not succeed as the line "Inside add User" is not ouput.Please where am I not doing it right? I will appreciate

Comment: where is the `@Path` definition?

Comment: @Path("/addName") sorry i forgot to put it in here.even thought it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have following @Path on your method

```
@Path("/addName/{fname}/{sname}/{idno}")
@POST
public Response addName(@PathParam("fname") String fName,
                           @PathParam("sname") String sName,
                           @PathParam("idno") String idNo) {
```

Comment: how to parse values using angular to this method??

Comment: @neo2100 You may want to be specific on your questions. Also, need to get some research done for understanding the basics.